# Trying Subclassing on Console

Tags: c, winapi

I want to trap keyboard messages in a console application, so I tried this:

```
HWND GetConsoleHwnd(void)
{
    #define SIZEBUF 1024
    char szBuffer[SIZEBUF];

    GetConsoleTitle(szBuffer, SIZEBUF);

    #undef SIZEBUF
    return FindWindow(NULL, szBuffer);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ConsoleProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            switch (wParam)
            {
               //VK Cases
            }
            break;
    }

    return CallWindowProc(OldConsoleProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

this in main:

```
HWND hwndConsole = GetConsoleHwnd();
OldConsoleProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLong(hwndConsole, GWL_WNDPROC,
                               ConsoleProc);
```

and this Global Var: `WNDPROC       OldConsoleProc;`

but it doesnt work, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work?"  What behavior did you expect and what did you observe?

Comment: You shouldn't need to search using `FindWindow` to get the console window handle - just use `GetConsoleWindow` (since Vista).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't subclass a window of another process this way. [You can do it with hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5264/Cross-Process-Subclassing) but I wouldn't recommend trying this on console window. [`ReadConsoleInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is low-level enough, and it's as far as you can get without ugly nonportable hacks (I'm not even sure there *are* some events reaching `WndProc` when the console window is full screen).

Comment: Helpful but the messages works in fullscreen. the only thing that won't post is Control+C and Control+Break from the keyboard that can be handled from a console handler. msgs could come from task manager ALT+F4 or another application.