# Handling drag and drop files in a running Windows console application

Tags: c++, winapi, drag-and-drop, console-application

First, to clarify, I am *not* asking how to drag-and-drop a file onto an exe's icon. I want to know how to handle drag and drop onto an **already running** win32 console application. I'm also *not* asking how to handle drag and drop inside of WinMain based applications through the Windows message pump. I want to do this inside of a program with the entry point *int main()* that doesn't have a WndProc (yet) or anything.

That said, I'm wondering if my goal is achievable (and hoping that it is).

I have a server application that is running within a console window. Due to a large codebase and a lot of weird coupling, it is an 'output only' console for all intensive purposes. Within it though, I can still handle things like key presses, as I have an update loop ticking. I'd like to be able to drag and drop files full of commands (which use a custom syntax) onto my running application and have it process them.

Is this possible to do? I was thinking that potentially I could get a pointer to the HWND of the console (which hopefully is a thing?), and then maybe subclass that window to use a custom WndProc to listen for the WM_DROPFILES message.

I've never really tried to set up handling of windows messages in an *int main()* program instead of a *WinMain* program, but I'm hoping it's somehow possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
***Weird solutions are fine.***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, a console window does not support drag&drop by default.  You can always create your own separate popup window with its own message loop so the user has something to drag items onto.

To use drag&drop on the console window itself, try using [`GetConsoleWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the console HWND, then either:

1. subclass the HWND using [`SetWindowLong/Ptr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`SetWindowSubClass()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102(v=vs.85).aspx), then register the HWND using [`DragAcceptFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776406(v=vs.85).aspx) to start receiving `WM_DROPFILES` messages.  Be sure to call `DragAcceptFiles()` again to stop receiving the messages and then unhook your subclass before exiting the app.
2. implement the [`IDropTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679679(v=vs.85).aspx) interface and then register the HWND using [`RegisterDragDrop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405(v=vs.85).aspx) to start receiving notifications.  Be sure to call [`RevokeDragDrop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692643(v=vs.85).aspx) before exiting the app.

`WM_DROPFILES` is easier to code for, but `IDropTarget` is more flexible as it handles virtual items as well as physical files.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! I'm gonna leave it open for a bit longer to see if any real weird solutions come though, but this is a solid response. I didn't know about the differences between WM_DROPFILES and the IDropTarget. The server is already using some MFC somewhere so this might be viable.

Comment: Hmm, no, the console window is not actually owned by the console program.  Subclassing it is therefore a complete dead end.  Covered by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788134/trying-subclassing-on-console) as well.

Comment: If the program is the first process running in the console then it does own the console window (`GetWindowThreadProcessId()` returns the same IDs as `GetCurrentProcessId()` and `GetCurrentThreadId()`) but oddly subclassing fails (`SetWindowLong/Ptr()` returns error 5). If the program is not the first process in the console then it will not own the console window, though it will perform I/O using the existing console window.

Comment: I even tried `SetWindowsHookEx()`, and although it was able to install message hooks, it did not detect the `WM_DROPFILES` message. I did find that the console window has the `WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES` style enabled by default, so the console must have its own internal drag&drop handler, especially since I can drag a file over the window and the cursor changes to show a drop is allowed.

Comment: If you drop a file on a cmd.exe console the file path is pasted into the command line so I'd say that's what the drop handler is for. I don't think there's a way to hook into this however. Although to a running console process it might just look like the user typed the name of a file, so maybe that is enough for what the OP wants to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation. It looks like I'll have to shut down this investigation for the time being... Creating a secondary listener window may be my only hope.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please drop files and press [Enter] when done ...\n";

    std::vector< std::string > files;

    for( int ch = _getch(); ch != '\r'; ch = _getch() ) {

        std::string file_name;

        if( ch == '\"' ) {  // path containing spaces. read til next '"' ...

            while( ( ch = _getch() ) != '\"' )
                file_name += ch;

        } else { // path not containing spaces. read as long as chars are coming rapidly.

            file_name += ch;

            while( _kbhit() )
                file_name += _getch();
        }

        files.push_back( file_name );
    }

    std::cout << "You dropped these files:\n";

    for( auto & i : files )
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Add some description so the other can understand your code and answer for this question.

Comment: @Charlie, because the Win32 console window implementation has this built-in drop handler routine -- completely opaquely to user code. (Note: this is not just some "default" behavior in the sense that there's no way to customize it, AFAIK. E.g. window subclassing won't work, because console processes can't change the window procedure that runs their window (basically because it's managed by the console host process ("CSRSS", or some of its relatives), not the application itself).)